# How to deny mouse right-click option in Ubuntu 20.04.5?

Tags: mouse, mate, ubuntu-mate

I have implemented ubuntu-20.04.5 LTS mate desktop-1.24.0 on AWS Cloud to access desktop applications. I need to restrict mouse right click option in ubuntu mate desktop. This right click should disable in Desktop only, Not in applications. Can any one please share the configuration steps to disable mouse right-click option in Ubuntu Mate Desktop?

[Mate-desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LAKq.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried disabling Caja from handling the desktop by running `dconf write /org/mate/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons false`

Comment: Hi mchid, I tried with dconf write /org/mate/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons false. But desktop icons too missing after executed. I Would like to disable right-click option in Desktop only.

Comment: HI, Is possible to remove right-click menu's?

Comment: May I ask why you would like to remove the right-click menu? Desktop icons are missing because Caja is no longer handling the desktop and without that, there should be no right-click menu.

Comment: Hi mchid, We need to restrict the user to open terminal using right-click, create folder using right click in desktop. Is possible to remove options from right-click menu, like open terminal, create folder, create document?

Comment: Yes, I realize these are the options available but you still haven't explained why you want to deny these options. This seems sort of like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so it might help us to know your actual problem rather than how to achieve your proposed solution to that problem. If you simply want to get rid of the right click option, you can use dconf (or you could use tweaks) to disable desktop icons, preventing Caja from operating on the desktop. The right click menu comes from Caja and your desktop is your Desktop directory.

Comment: We are providing modelling application to end users to access with help of AWS Nice DCV. Here, the user should not open terminal or creating folder on desktop. The end user should not use command prompt. That's why I need to restrict the mouse right-click option in desktop.

Comment: Hi Mchid, I already hide desktop Icons using Mate tweaks and I allowed only my application to end users. But, My aim is to disable the mouse right-click option in Desktop only or I need to remove the menu options (like customize) when i right-click on desktop only. I hope you understand